# android databinding in custom controls

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

In official android docs - there is some guidance how to use databinding in fragments and activities. However I have pretty complex picker with high ammount of settings. Something like:

```
class ComplexCustomPicker extends RelativeLayout{
    PickerViewModel model;
}
```

So my question is what method of the picker I need to override to be able use binding inside it and not seting/checking individual values like textfield, etc?

And second question - how could I pass viewmodel to my picker in xml file, do I need some custom attributes for that?

Answer (score 3):

I think using Custom Setters will solve your problem. [Check this section](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html?hl=en#custom_setters) in developers guidelines.

I can give you a brief example for it. Suppose the name of your view is `CustomView` and of your viewmodel is `ViewModel`, then in any of your class, create a method like this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:viewmodel"})
public static void bindCustomView(CustomView view, ViewModel model) {
    // Do whatever you want with your view and your model
}
```

And in your layout, do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.pkgname.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    // Your layout

    <com.pkgname.CustomView 
    // Other attributes
    app:viewmodel="@{viewModel}"
    />

</layout>
```

And from your `Activity` use this to set the ViewModel:

```
MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```

Or you can directly inflate from your custom view:

```
LayoutViewCustomBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.layout_view_custom, this, true);
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```

Comment: Good answer! Also, if you happen to have a setter method on your `ComplexCustomPicker` that takes the `PickerViewModel`, then you don't need the `BindingAdaper`. Android Data Binding automatically tries to find something with the name setXxx where Xxx is the attribute. So if `ComplexCustomPicker` has a method `void setViewModel(PickerViewModel)`, you can use the attribute `app:viewModel="@{viewModel}"` just like above. This technique means that you're tying your view to your model types, but that may be fine in your app.