# Custom XML attribute on android databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I have used AppCompatSpinner for my fragment and I want to use `setOnItemSelectedListener()` in my layout. I tried to use  the tutorial section from here

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html?hl=en#custom_setters

but it does not provide a complete example to do the simple action. And I also look for the answer from here

[android databinding in custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965789/android-databinding-in-custom-controls)

and I still dun understand how to do it. **I would like to have a complete example to do the simple custom binding with some attributes that's not existed in xml attribute but it is useful in the UI control**

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:apps="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.my.OldHandlerInterface"/>
    </data>

    <merge
        tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_stock_replacement">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/exist_eqpt_card"
            style="@style/sccardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:visibility="@{oldObj.updateOld_mode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spn_status"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/chk_installed"
                    apps:adapter="@{statusAdapter}"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

    </merge>
</layout>
```

Here is my fragment

```
public class ReplacementFragment extends QRScanFragment {
    ../
    @BindingAdapter("app:setOnItemSelectedListener")
    public static void setOnItemSelectedListener(AppCompatSpinner view, int pos) {
        //do sth
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.binding, container, false);
        String[] status = new String[]{"Spare", "Lost", "Damage", "Faulty"};
        statusAdapter = new StatusAdapter(getActivity(), status);
        binding.setHandler(new Handler());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        AppCompatSpinner lAppCompatSpinner = (AppCompatSpinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spn_status);
        lAppCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need anything special to assign to the OnItemSelectedListener:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spn_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chk_installed"
    android:onItemSelectedListener="@{myItemSelectedListener}"
    apps:adapter="@{statusAdapter}"/>
```

The above assumes a `myItemSelectedListener` variable in your layout of the type `OnItemSelectedListener`.

If you want to use only the onItemSelected or onNothingSelected, you can use the attribute in your layout already:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spn_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chk_installed"
    android:onItemSelected="@{handler::onItemSelected}"
    apps:adapter="@{statusAdapter}"/>
```

This assumes a method on `handler`'s class:

```
public class Handler {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can also use a lambda expression:

```
android:onItemSelected="@{(p, v, pos, id) -> handler.onItemSelected(v, pos)}"
```

Here, handler's class has a method:

```
public class Handler {
    public void onItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        //...
    }
}
```

In all these cases, you must assign the handler or listener in the `onCreateView`, just as you're doing above with the `binding.setHandler(...)` call. You don't need to call `lAppCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(...)` because it will be done as part of the binding.