# Is there attribute like android:onClick for spinner?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, onclick, spinner

I want to find any way to run a method when i select any item in spinner like Button attribute android:onClick or something else.

Comment: well yes there is! its onItemSelected! please search google for it here is the referral link for the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: `spinner like Button` elaborate, please. use `onItemSelected`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, you mean i can use android:onItemSelected in spinner tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) and follow this post [Custom XML attribute on android databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136713/custom-xml-attribute-on-android-databinding).

Or the easiest way is to implement `OnItemSelectedListener` on your `Activity`.

Set listener to your spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Override `onItemSelected()` method:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Refer: [How can I use onItemSelected in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151414/how-can-i-use-onitemselected-in-android)

Comment: when i put android:onItemSelectedListener it say "Unknown attribute android:onItemSelectedListener", what can i do ?

Comment: Instead of `android:onItemSelectedListener`, you can implement `OnItemSelectedListener` on your `Activity`, which is by far the easiest and cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement OnItemSelectedListener

```
YourClass implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

Then in onCreate

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
```

and overrided method

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}
```

where position is the position of the item that you selected from spinner. Hope it helps.